# Add line and drag down certain content

Tags: vba, excel

I have a document which is used to list staff requests. I want a button to add a new row (new staff request) and insert certain things into columns automatically. So I want it to generate the next ref# (`XX-01`/`XX-02` etc.) in one column and also add in the date the request was raised.

Is this possible?

*Copy (not by OP) of comment:*

The current code I use is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A11").Select  
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A11:AA11").Select  
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin  
Range("A11:AA11").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)  
End Sub
```

This adds a new row and formats it as required. However even if I record a new macro to drag down the required fields (ref# etc) the next time I add a row it's added above the previously added row (as row 11 becomes 12 and so will always be added above).

Comment: yes. it's possible. what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Yes. Do it manually, recording it as a macro. Then simply copy the generated code and modify as/if required.

Comment: @enhzflep Although I understand your point of view, I'm not sure that it's a good idea to motivate people towards the macro recorder. The thing opens up a shitload of potential bugs and generates a mass of useless code. Although it allows us to solve a problem faster, as a community I think that we give a wrong message. The person who uses it is put on the wrong track, and will probably be stuck there for a long time.

Comment: I refer to this question that just entered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682362/excel-using-vb-macro

Comment: @KimGysen - I wonder, what approach you advocate, given your position on the macro recorder? I've used it for years as a much faster way to understanding how to implement functionality than either the MrExcel site (whatever it's url is) or than the often brutally painful excel help system. The example you've shown simply says to me "don't bite off more than you can chew" or "learn to walk before you try to run" - I've used the recorder many, many times in conjunction with the object browser and help system to quickly ascertain how to tell excel what to do when writing c++ COM code.

Comment: @enhzflep Well, the approach I usually advocate is to start with the logical hierarchy of the Excel Application object which is (application)-sheet-range/cell and to learn how to name and call these simple objects. It takes 10mins when example code is offered. The link I've added shows the path many starters take and which is naturally taught by the macro-recorder: .activate .select activesheet.save etc... only to learn much later that these are bug monsters. When I started working in the VBA team @ GDF Suez, they immediately discouraged me to use them and it is generally accepted custom.

Comment: I'm not trying to say that we should give a course to every person on this forum, and it's nothing personal; it's just that the macro recorder has done more harm to companies, as well as the reputation of VBA as a programming language than it has helped. While it is actually still by far the best solution out there for what concerns support for the MS Office pack.

Comment: @KimGysen - sounds like a perfectly reasonable approach to me. You've almost certainly more experience working with VBA in an enterprise situation than I do. I've come at the approach with a view to understanding what/how it's done, rather than making something work(correctly) as quickly as possible, as is often the case in paid positions. Thanks for your thoughts, my +1.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the first comment above (etc) despite the tags you might like to consider non-VBA alternatives. Perhaps enter into a Table (Insert > Tables - Table), say with `="XX-"&ROW()-1` in the Request# column (which should automatically adjust when dragged down) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`;` for entry of the date.

Comment: The current code I use is:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A11").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A11:AA11").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
Range("A11:AA11").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub

This adds a new row and formats it as required. However even if I record a new macro to drag down the required fields (ref# etc) the next time I add a row it's added above the previously added row (as row 11 becomes 12 and so will always be added above).